# Implement wallet abstraction locally : Do I need a bundler node?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, account-abstraction, erc-4337

I'm trying to implement wallet abstraction locally using Anvil.
I've deployed the required contracts.

Now I'm wondering if I have to set up a local node bundler for my local Anvil network to bundle the userOps into a tx or if I can do it another way.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same questions as you too, Btw I want to ask about your experience, when you create a smart account, do you need to use different private keys for each? Also, do you implement paymaster for your userOps